# Rounding a float to the closest integer within a distance cutoff

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` with one column that specifies IDs and a few others that have numerical values. In each of these numerical value columns, there's a fraction of integers and a fraction of floats:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("id_",sample(LETTERS,100,replace=T)),
                 var_1 = c(as.integer(runif(80,0,3)),runif(20,0,2))[permute::shuffle(100)],
                 var_2 = c(as.integer(runif(90,0,3)),runif(10,0,2))[permute::shuffle(100)],
                 var_3 = c(as.integer(runif(70,0,3)),runif(30,0,2))[permute::shuffle(100)])
```

I'm looking for a fast `function` that will round each float in each of the numerical columns to the closest integer if that distance is less than 0.1, otherwise convert it to `NA`.

Right now I have this:

```
df[,-1] <- do.call(cbind,lapply(colnames(df)[-1], function(i){
  dists <- ceiling(df[,i])-df[,i]
  idx <- which(dists > 0.5)
  if(length(idx) > 0) dists[idx] <- dists[idx]-1
  idx <- which(abs(dists) > 0.1)
  if(length(idx) > 0) dists[idx] <- NA
  return(df[,i]+dists)
}))
```

But wondering if there's anything faster/more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can also be done without a loop by creating a logical `matrix`

```
dists <- ceiling(df[-1]) - df[-1]
i1 <- dists  > 0.5
dists[i1] <- dists[i1] -1
i2 <- abs(dists) > 0.1
dists[i2] <- NA
df[-1] <- df[-1] + dists
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a tiny bit faster and more compact:

```
df[,-1][abs(round(df[,-1]) - df[,-1]) >.1] <- NA
df <- data.frame(id=df[,1], round(df[,-1]))
```